# Переборка двумерного масива в игре "Жизнь"

Tags: javascript

Пишу вариацию игры "Жизнь" ( Conway's Game of Life).
Пришла идея  выводить количество оддновременно живых клеток. И тут я столкнулся с трудностью. Хотя мне вроде показалось это простым, так как логика игры незамысловата. Есть двумерный масив который делит поле игры на аккуратные квадратики. Если в ячейке "1" клетку закрашиваем(это живая клетка) Если ноль, клетка мертвая, цвета нет.

Как результат у меня или огромные цифры так как видимо сумируются все еденицы что пояляются на поле. Или не работает. 
Помогите решить данную проблемку. И что я делаю не так.:(
https://jsfiddle.net/pridan/xg8opvqr/

```
<canvas id ='canvas' ></canvas>
<p>Циклы</p><span id="count">0</span>
<p>Популяция</p><div id="cell-life">0</div>
<button id="start-evolution">Start</button>
<button id="stop-evolution">Stop</button>
<button id="next-generation" hidden>Next</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>


(function () {
  // initialParams();
// function initialParams() {
//
//
// }
  // var enterSize = prompt("Введите размер поля?", "");
  // var enterSpeed = prompt("Введите скорость?", "");

  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var size = 500;
  var meshSize = size / 10;
  canvas.width = size;
  canvas.height = size;
  var speed = 100;

  var arr = [];
  var count = 0;
  var countPopulation = 0;
  var timer;

  init();

  function init() {
    initButtons();
    initGameFiaeld();
  }
//вызов очистки поля
  function clear() {
    stop();
    clearCanvas();
    resetGenerations();
    resetGameField();
    canvasBoard();
  }
//Рамка игрового поля
  var canvasBoard = function () {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0,size, size);
  };
  canvasBoard();
//Рамка игрового поля функция очистки поля
  function clearCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
  }

  function drawPoint() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, size, size);
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          ctx.fillRect(j * 10, i * 10, 10, 10);
        }
      }
    }
  }
//Рисуем точки
  function initGameFiaeld() {
    canvas.addEventListener('click', clickPosition);
    function clickPosition(event) {
      var x = event.offsetX;
      var y = event.offsetY;
      x = Math.floor(x / 10); 
      y = Math.floor(y / 10);

      for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
          if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
            arr[y][x] = 1;
          }
        }
      }
      arr[y][x] = 1;
      drawPoint();
      canvasBoard();
    }
//Размечаю поле
    var goLIfe = function () {
      for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }();
  }
//Функция сброса очистки поля
  function resetGameField() {
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    drawPoint();

  }
//Иницилизация кнопок
  function initButtons() {
    var startBtn = document.getElementById('start-evolution');
    var stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop-evolution');
    var clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear');

    startBtn.addEventListener('click', start);
    stopBtn.addEventListener('click', stop);
    clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clear);
  }
//Проверка условий существования точек
  function startLife() {
    var arr2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      arr2[i] = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        var neighbors = 0;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][j] == 1) neighbors++ ;
        if (arr[i][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][j] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[i][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][checkPlus(j) + 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkPlus(i) + 1][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;
        if (arr[checkMinus(i) - 1][checkMinus(j) - 1] == 1) neighbors++;

        if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
          arr2[i][j] = neighbors == 3 ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
          arr2[i][j] = neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3 ? 1 : 0;
        }
      }
    }
    arr = arr2;

    drawPoint();
    canvasBoard();
    count++;
    timer = setTimeout(startLife, speed);
    updateGenerations();

  }

 //Тут проблема
//Cчётчик для подсчёта живых клеток
  function updatePopulation() {
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          console.log(arr);
          countPopulation +=1;
        }
      }
    }
    var populationDiv = document.getElementById('cell-life');
    populationDiv.innerHTML = countPopulation;
  }

  updatePopulation();

//Счетчик циклов(поколений)
  function updateGenerations() {
    var generationDiv = document.getElementById('count');
    generationDiv.innerHTML = count;
  }

//Сброс циклов(поколений)
  function resetGenerations() {
    count = 0;
    updateGenerations();
  }

//Проверка границ
  function checkMinus(i) {
    if (i == 0) return meshSize;
    else return i;
  }

//Проверка границ
  function checkPlus(i) {
    if (i == meshSize - 1) return -1;
    else return i;
  }

  function start() {
    startLife();
  }

  function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

})();
```

Comment: 1. У Вас `updatePopulation()` вызывается ровно один раз, при инициализации. 2. `countPopulation` у Вас тоже приравнивается нулю ровно один раз, при инициализации, после этого он только увеличивается, отсюда и огромные цифры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

счетчик не обнуляется

```
 function updatePopulation() {
  countPopulation=0
    for (var i = 0; i < meshSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < meshSize; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1) {
          console.log(arr);
          countPopulation +=1;
        }
      }
    }
    var populationDiv = document.getElementById('cell-life');
    populationDiv.innerHTML = countPopulation;
  }
```